# Import graphics between differents Watson IoT dashboards

Tags: import, dashboard, watson-iot

I have a board on my Watson IoT dashboard, which I use to monitor temperature real-time with a line graphic.

I have a second dashboard with a different organisation, and I want to import the graphic which is in the board in the first dashboard, without making again the same graphic.

I've already tried that solution and, even if possibile, it wouldn't be efficent. I mean, I already have the data on IoT why sending from IoT to Iot?

So, can i display on, let's call it... dashboard2, the board with the temperature (or any other property) which is in dashboard1 **without sending or duplicate data on dashboard2?**

If so, how can i do that? It's almost a week that I'm searching, and I start to doubt that something like this actually exists...

Comment: Are you saying you want to display the data from the two different organizations in one graph?  Watson IoT segregates data based on organizations, so I believe the 2 dashboard you mentions are for different orgs.   You would probably need to create your own application which can authenticate with both orgs and use the data to publish visually in a graphic display.

Comment: Err... No, the organizations are distinct and separate, the graphic is on dashboard1, what I want to do it's some sort of Ctrl+c , ctrl+v , so that i can see the same graphic, real-time, on both dashboards

Comment: If you can include a screenshot that may be helpful.

Comment: I would love to... but seems i can't paste it... :(

Comment: If you have a screenshot you should be able to edit your original question and provide more details and images.